# React-native app performace degraded after enabling fabric renderer with new architecture in React-native App with Expo ReactNativeHostWrapper

Tags: react-native, expo, localauthentication

React-native app wrapped inside Expo ReactNativeHostWrapper used for expo local authentication when used with new fabric renderer with rn 0.72.3 makes app run very slow and lags in UI rendering.

If I remove expo related dependencies specially ReactNativeHostWrapper to wrap DefaultReactNativeHost makes app smooth and run faster.

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
import com.kroosx4v.orientationmanager.OrientationManagerActivityLifecycleCallbacks;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new OrientationManagerActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
  }
  
  @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
    }

}
```